# How to make a table from a table of json rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

I have table like:

| value |
| --- |
| {"Date":"2022-10-31","Delta":5,"Comment":null} |
| {"Date":"2022-11-01","Delta":5,"Comment":null} |

How can I get a table like:

| Date | Delta | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-31 | 5 | null |
| 2022-11-01 | 5 | null |

Data:

```
DECLARE @r TABLE (
   value VARCHAR(255)
)
INSERT INTO @r VALUES
     (N'{"Date":"2022-10-31","Delta":5,"Comment":null}'),
     (N'{"Date":"2022-11-01","Delta":5,"Comment":null}');
```

Comment: If you use SQL Server 2016+, you need `OPENJSON()` and an additional `APPLY` operator: `SELECT j.* FROM @r r CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(r.[value]) WITH ([Date] varchar(10), [Delta] int, [Comment] varchar(255)) j`. It's good to read the documentation first.

Comment: The last several versions of SQL Server have very good json support, which version of SQL Server are you using? If it's an unsupported version you should indicate/tag in your question.

Comment: Sorry, next time I will indicate SQL Server version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT j.* 
FROM @r
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(value)
            WITH 
            (
                Date DATE,
                Delta INT,
                Comment VARCHAR(50)
            ) j;
```

Should give you the desired output.

Comment: Clearly the preferred approach (+1), but just for fun, how would you handle a bogus date in the source JSON

Comment: @JohnCappelletti: as in an invalid date? Like Nov 31st or something like that? Or with invalid data (alphanumerics) in the string? In that case - you'd probably have to convert to a string representation (in the `WITH` clause) and store it as such - and later on go over it again and do a `TRY_CAST(.... AS DATE)` to filter out the bad data

Answer (score 2):

Just another option demonstrating the use of `JSON_VALUE()`

```
Select Date   =JSON_VALUE(value,'$.Date')   -- could wrap in a try_convert(date,...)
      ,Delta  =JSON_VALUE(value,'$.Delta')  -- could wrap in a try_convert(int,...)
      ,Comment=JSON_VALUE(value,'$.Comment')
 From  @r
```